# How to search with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I have 5 Check boxes,

```
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="manhattan" value="Manhattan" >Manhattan</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="bronx" value="Bronx" >Bronx</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="brooklyn" value="Brooklyn" >Brooklyn</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="queen" value="Queen" >Queen</label>
```

I want to search

```
---------------------------------
id   |        location
---------------------------------
1    |  Manhattan,Brooklyn,Queen
2    |  Queen,Brooklyn
---------------------------------
```

Here is my query

```
extract($_POST);
$locprefervals = $manhattan.",".$bronx.",".$brooklyn.",".$queen.",".$staten;
$locprefer = rtrim($locprefervals,',');

$query = "select * from tbl where location='".$locprefer ."'";
```

When the user checked a location in check boxes i need to compare the data from my table "location" each comma separated values.

Comment: this is why you shouldn't store comma separated values in column. Normalize

Comment: And add a name to your checkboxis like `city[]`, and then `join(',',$_POST['city']);`

Comment: Can't you just use `LIKE`? $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE location LIKE '%".$locprefer ."%'";

Comment: sorry its not work

Comment: any other way to separate by comma and search by each values